# How can I connect to posgresql with new connection on RStudio

Tags: r, postgresql

I want to connect RStudio to a database in PostgreSQL. So firstly following the instructions I modified the odbcinst.ini file:

```
[PostgreSQL Driver]
Driver          = /usr/local/lib/psqlodbcw.so
```

Ok, so now appears a PostgreSQL selectable in connection. And then I tried to make the connection:

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                 .connection_string = "Driver={PostgreSQL Driver};",
                 dbname = 'name', 
                 host = 'host',
                 user = 'user',
                 password = 'pass',
                 port = 5432,
                 timeout = 10)
```

But it returns me an error:

```
rror: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:983: 00000: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I have tried so far:

```
drv <- dbDriver("RPostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv,
                 dbname = 'name', 
                 host = 'host',
                 user = 'user',
                 password = 'pass',
                 port = 5432)
```

That works but I'm unable to navigate the database (I mean, to see the tables and connection status) in RStudio.

[image]

My question is: Should I change my driven in odbcinst.ini? What would be the .so file? Any help pointing what to do will be greatly appreciated. By the way I'm running on Mac, and the host is in Amazon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error this worked for me:

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                 Driver = "PostgreSQL Driver",
                 Database = 'name', 
                 Server = 'host',
                 UID = 'user',
                 PWD = 'pass',
                 Port = 5432,
                 timeout = 10)
```

Voila, now I can see the tables in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `RPostgres` can help you out

```
con <- RPostgres::dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(),
                            dbname = 'name', 
                            host = 'host',
                            user = 'user',
                            password = 'pass',
                            port = 5432)
```

Comment: Hello @Nick, indeed it creates the connection, but I can't see it in "connection" tab in RStudio. By the way, thank you for your time in answering this question.

Comment: Yeah it won't appear in that tab, but you can still access it for example with `tbl(con, "table")`

Comment: Hello @Nick, yes but I wanted the list of tables to appear in RStudio. Anyway your answer gave me an idea and led me to the solution.